# how to set pdf page settings to print properties dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-flex, pdf, printing

Hi all I want to know about how to set pdf page settings to print properties dialog box?

For Example,
If my PDF page settings is Landscape then Layout automatically shows Landscape not Portrait. and If my PDF page settings is Protrait then Layout automatically shows Portrait.

I have make R&D lot on this topic but not found any satisfied link. Please give me satisfied answer. this will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a program, or are you looking for a utility that does this?

Comment: I want any of this either utility or in a program... both will be acceptable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF is a device-independent format and doesn't not include functionality to set print dialog parameters. JDF was designed to compliment PDF and contain process specific settings; however, it's not supported outside of large print workflows.