# Controlling the print options of a pdf

Tags: .net, pdf, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set pdf page settings to print properties dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922323/how-to-set-pdf-page-settings-to-print-properties-dialog)

I am producing a number of PDFs using either SSRS or using an HTML to PDF component. What I want to do for each document is to set the first page to print to tray 1 and subsequent pages.

Is there anyway to do this? System.Drawing.Printing and System.Printing seem like good candidates but they don't seem to be useful for PDFs (i may be wrong). The Adobe sdk doesn't at first glance seem to have that level of granularity either.

Comment: I've got a feeling that GhostScript is the answer to my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating a profile in your print options on the machine from which you are printing?  You can specify a different paper source for page 1 and subsequent pages.  That seems to me to be just what you're looking for.

Comment: can you provide me a code sample on how to do this programatically?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot specify this kind of information in the PDF file itself.
You do have a few options from the printing application:

**Option 1**: Using P/Invoke and the commercial library [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex/) *(usual disclaimer applies)*:

For silent printing with a custom configuration you could try using Win32 API. You need to create a DEVMODE structure, and use that during printing.

This article in MSDN may help:
[How To Modify Printer Settings with the DocumentProperties() Function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167345)

In Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX, you can set a DEVMODE structure to the document object before calling the [Document.Print](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_ACTIVE_X/Using_the_PDF_Creator_Control/Methods/Printing/Print_Method.htm) method.

```
byte[] devmode = GetMyDevModeAsByteArray();
pdfCreator1.Document.AttributeByName(”PrinterDevMode”).Value = devmode;
```

I must say that I have not tested this. The DEVMODE structure that is used on the ”PrinterDevMode” attribute is meant to be generated by the ActiveX control itself by showing the print settings dialog, but I think it is safe to assume that it will work if it is obtained by other means, since it is the printer driver who ultimately defines the structure in all cases. 
I may test this later if I have time.

Amyuni PDF Creator also has the option of selecting a paper tray according to the page size specified for each page in a PDF file. So if this is what your are actually trying to achieve, you can use the ["FormToBinMap" document attribute](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Developer_Documentation.htm#Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Object_Attributes/Document_Attributes.htm) to configure the tray you want to use for each page size. You do not need to customize the DEVMODE structure in this case.

**Option 2:** Using WPF:

If you use WPF, and if the target printer provides an XPS driver, then you might be able to do this using [PrintTicket.InputBin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket.inputbin.aspx)

From MSDN:

**PrintTicket.InputBin** Property:

> Gets or sets a value indicating what input bin (paper tray) to use.

You could use Amyuni PDF Creator .Net or ActiveX to convert your PDF file to XPS.
Or if a GPL license suits your needs, you could use ghostscript to convert your files to raster images, then [wrap that in XPS files](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsxps/thread/8c6eb3ee-f541-4e00-b0e9-a982db7c73f5/).

**Option 3:**

If your target printer is a PostScript printer, you could split your files in 1-page files, then convert each file to the PostScript format using ghostscript, then specify the tray for each page before printing it, but as far as I know this last part is device-specific (I might be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

This is not solvable in PDF, as PDF is hardware-agnostic.

[JDF](http://www.adobe.com/products/jdf/) was developed for that, but only a printing house will be able to handle that.

Comment: Is there no way to set default print options